# I want to rotate a transitioned image by bottom right corner of image

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to transition an image, then rotate it from the bottom right corner.

```css
    .Wrapper {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background- color: yellow;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .Bottle {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
      animation: MoveBottle 10s infinite;
      transform-origin: bottom right;
    }
    
    @keyframes MoveBottle {
      10% {
        transform: translate(50px, -90px);
        color: green;
      }
      30% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        color: red;
      }
      80% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        color: red;
      }
      95% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        color: black;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
      }
    }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="Wrapper">empty the glass
    <img class="Bottle" src="http://segalandassociates.com/images/eglass.png" alt="Champagne Bottle">
  </div>
  <br>
```

At the 30%, I want to rotate the image with the center rotation being the bottom right of the image.

Can anyone help me do that?
[W3 Schools Tryit](https://alansegal.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2022-08-11-SE.html)

Comment: Each of your transforms nullifies the previous transform - is that what you intend?

Comment: I would like to move the (image) glass up on the Y axis, and to the right on the X axis; THEN rotate it in its moved position. Like lifting a glass from the side of a sink over the sink, then rotating it to empty it out. (I know I have rotate 90 instead of 180, but that's because I am going to rotate to 180 a little at a time - but that adds stuff to the relevent code) Then  move it back to its original position.

Comment: You need each transform to include previous ones if you want the previous ones to be 'remembered'. See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: If I do: "  10% {transform:translate(50px,-90px);color:green;}
    30% {transform:translate(50px,-90px);rotate(90deg);color:red;}", the glass still rotates the 90, but the glass still falls to the bottom, instead of staying at the translated (50,-90) location.

Comment: You need spaces not a semi colon between the different transform values. Please see the MDN reference above.

Comment: Ah. Missed it by "this much". I had forgotten about that. Works great now, thank you very much!